# How to create a path to another module in cucumber java?

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I have a question about cucumber, I'm integrating cucumber into an existing java project.
In the past many modules are defined in the project.
The steps are defined in the "testApi" module. The test classes and the feature file are defined in the "integrationTest" module.

example:

```
->project
  ->testApi
    ->src
      ->test
        ->java
          ->com
            ->apiXyz
              myTestSteps.java
  ->integrationTest
    ->src
      ->test
        ->java
          ->com
            ->cucumber
              myTestClass.java
      ->resources
        ->cucumber
           myTest.feature
```

How do I specify the path to the step definition (myTestSteps.java) in myTestClass.java?
With "glue" I can only specify steps in the same src path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hey You can Integrate Your Test Cases Module Wise:**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xxx.awsam</groupId>
<artifactId>AW-END-TO-END-TESTS</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.1034-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>AW-END-TO_END_TESTS</name>
<modules>
    <module>Module1</module>
    <module>Module1</module>
</modules>
```

**For Runner Class:**

```
     features = "classpath:cucumber/myTest.feature",
     glue = {"YourStepDefPackage:com.apiXyz"}
```